# Как работает вывод в команде top?

Tags: linux, c

Каким образом команда top обновляет таблицу без очистки консоли?

Я пробовал обновлять через system("clear"), как показано в интернете, и через puts("[H[2J"), как показано в исходниках, но это далеко не то же самое.

Comment: По поводу top не знаю, но, например, программа [htop](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htop) построена поверх [ncurses](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). Библиотеку ncurses можно использовать на разных языках, включая Python, Ruby, Javascript.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, top не чистит экран, а просто с помощью [ANSI-кодов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI#CSI_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B) двигает курсор в нужные места и пишет новый текст поверх старого

Comment: @andreymal, почти наверняка (если терминал эту фичу поддерживает) он еще и скролит (тоже escape-последовательностями) вверх-вниз диапазоны строк экрана. Такой софт (сравнение текущего и целевого образа экрана и построение оптимального набора операций вывода) используется во многих "старых"  (до эры X-windows) программах

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо джентльменам в комментариях. Они направили на верный путь.

Вот такое заклинание у меня вышло:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CONSOLE_BOTTOM_CLEAR "\e[0J"

int main(char argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("\e[s"); //сохраняет позицию курсора
    while(1) {
        printf("%d", i);
        ++i;
        puts(CONSOLE_BOTTOM_CLEAR); //чистит все, что внизу до дна
        printf("\e[u"); //восстанавливает позицию курсора
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

Однако это сделано своими руками. Как исходник работает для меня до сих пор загадка.

Comment: Зачем гадать? Посмотрите в исходниках.

Comment: Работает он, основываясь на свойствах терминала запомнить положение курсора (а курсор, это позиция экрана, начиная с которой терминал отображает посылаемые ему символы) и  переместить курсор в ранее запомненную позицию. `puts()` тут нужен для выталкивания буфера из-за того, что по умолчанию stdout построчно (line) буферизирован. (в принципе можно ничего не стирать, поскольку обычно там и так пусто, а вместо вывода '\n' через puts вызвать `fflush(stdout)` (что будет, сами попробуйте))